# AWS Lambda Authorizer function can't access internet with same configuration as non authorizer function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I gave my functions the exact same configurations like the images below.

But the functions in `server-aws-development` can access internet (tested it with GET call to google.com), but the authorizer function `server-aws-token_authorizer` can't. How is this possible?

[image: Screenshot 2021-12-10 at 17 04 02]
[image: Screenshot 2021-12-10 at 17 04 23]

Below the screenshot for the Route Table connected to the private subnets:

[image]

Below the screenshot for the Route Table for the public subnets:

[image]

Comment: Both functions are configured to use private and public subnets. So when you execute the function, it could be in any of these 4 subnets. I suppose the successful test was executed on the public subnet but when executing again (using the other function) it is executed on one of the privates. Have you checked that private subnets allows access to internet through a NAT Gateway?

Comment: @OmarRosadio I added screenshots for the route tables fort the subnets.

Comment: So this should give them internet access right?